# One-line equation with two columns

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I try to write an equation with two similar formulas, i.e.

`\begin{equation}
\qquad A_1 = B + C \qquad A_2 = D + E \qquad
\end{equation}`

Of course, instead of `\qquad`s I want to use something like `\hfill`.

I would also like to do the same with some text within, like

`\begin{equation}
\qquad A_1 = B + C \quad \text{and} \quad A_2 = D + E \qquad
\end{equation}`

Is there any prefered/"best" way for this?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 6):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environment provides this by default:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align}
  A_1 &= B + C & A_2 &= D + E
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  A_1 &= B + C &&\text{and} & A_2 &= D + E
\end{align}
\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just did not use the central &. Could you please also explain the use of extra &'s around \text{and}?